# GeoServer Clustering gives java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: geoserver, clustering

I have problems setting up a clustered GeoServer. So far I  have four instances (version 2.2.4) running on a ubuntu linux box with a shared data directory behind HAProxy.
I use one of the geoservers to configure the cluster (master) and reload configuration in the other instances (slaves). In practice I often get errors when reloading configuration on the slaves. Only restarting each instance in the cluster distributed the configuration to all instances. It seems that i am doing something wrong.

Has anyone some experiences in clustering GeoServer?

The cluster was set up according to http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/07/20/basic-tomcat-clustering-grails-applications
After installation a directory /var/lib/geoserver_data was added and in the startup scripts I set CATALINA_OPTS DGEOSERVER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/geoserver_data -DGWC_DISKQUOTA_DISABLED=true -DGWC_METASTORE_DISABLED=true

So all instances share the same data directory.

So far so good. Until additional data is added:
For adding data only one of the GeoServer instances is used. Adding - lets say a PostGIS layer - works fine. I can see the layer in the preview and use it as expected but when I go to the admin interface in of the other instances, hitting 'reload configuration' an error message greets me, saying:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Settings already exist for
> workspace 'abc'

Removing workspace 'abc' leads to

> "Settings already exist for workspace 'def'"

and so on.